# Do I need more fermentation? Why my sourdough is flattened?

Tags: fermentation, sourdough

From a few weeks I've been trying to make sourdough. The most successful recipe for me and for the time I have I found is [Easy Sourdough Bread Recipe using a stand mixer - Sourdough Lamination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnPiS4TuqDs) In the recipe it said that it needs 3 hours in room temperature + 30 min in refrigerator and then you bake.

Because I don't have that time in one I leave it on the counter for 1 hour then let the sourdough in the refrigerator overnight (10 hours) and bake it in the morning. The whole wheat flour I use is with 13% protein.

I found the dough "flattened" and without so much holes and somehow I feel like it's not so fermented. Is it possible for 10 hour fermentation in the refrigerator? How can I improve the dough and do I need more fermentation time maybe in room temperature? The dough is fine, not so wet it can be shaped. I added picture in the end to show what I mean.

**The recipe is:**

- 200 g. white flour
- 100 g. whole wheat flour
- 240 g. water
- 6 g salt
- 90g starter
- 40g pumpkin seeds

**Totals:**

- 345 g flour (45 from starter)
- 285 g water (45 from starter)
- 2% salt
- 82.6% hydration

[image]

Comment: The time will depend on the activity of your starter, but what's the rising, transferring and baking process - in the recipe and in your kitchen?  If I get enough rise for really big bubbles I only have to look at it funny and it collapses, let alone transfer it into the pan I bake it in.  I actually aim for a denser loaf because it makes better lunches IMO

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that's quite a decent looking loaf. It doesn't look dense or overly pancaked. The crumb is consistent, with good bubble formation. A lot of amateur bakers would be quite proud to achieve that result. So give yourself a pat on the back before you start trying to improve further.

Now, 82% hydration is quite high, even for a whole wheat loaf. High hydration free-form whole wheat loaves are notoriously difficult to shape well, simply because the dough is so loose. Careful shaping and skillful oven control (including steam) are necessary to get a good loft in those circumstances.

Now, three hours at room temperature is not enough time to develop significant sourdough taste. Neither is ten hours in the refrigerator. (Ten hours in a cool room would be closer.) As more fermentation occurs, however, the gluten structure will weaken, leading to a flatter loaf.

So overall, I'd suggest you try a lower hydration and a longer cold rest (but, if possible, at a slightly higher temperature than your refrigerator).

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation, till now I was only reading about how to make your own sourdough bread but there was no one to ask these questions so this would help me a lot. I was trying also to leave the dough in the refrigerator for 20 hours (so I can bake the dough the next evening) but I found it was flatter than ever. I will try lower hydration and longer rest on higher temperature than refrigerator as you recommend me and will make an update how it was going. Thanks a bunch again!